# Query regarding CounterSignature and Digital Signature

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, code-signing-certificate

I am having following doubts regarding digital certificates -

1. In the property pages on windows OS we see Digital signature Tab. In
      that tab we see digital signature list. If we select any one from
      that list and checked the details of it looks like shown below.
      I would like to know what is exact differences between the two
      highlighted sections(Signer Information and Countersignatures) in 
      the image that is shown?
       [image]
2. If anyone want to verify this executable which certificates or
   certificates chain needs to be present in his/her certificate
   stores? I see different certification chain for counter signature certificates.

Anyone may download and see this executable from following link -
https://www.veritas.com/content/support/en_US/vqa.html

Answer (score 0):

1. As per MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/desktop/SecGloss/c-gly

> **countersignature**
>
> A signature of an existing signature and message or a signature of an
>   existing signature. A countersignature is used to sign the encrypted
>   hash of an existing signature or to time stamp a message.

2. Yes the certificate chains may be different.